# jPlayer on mobile devices only starts playing at the second attempt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, jplayer

I am using jPlayer for a website plugin that plays MP3 files which are transmitted from a Server. When you include the main script in a website a button is added to the DOM structure that allows the user to open the player. When this button is clicked the structure of the player (buttons for play/pause, back, forward, stop) is added by createElement() and appendChild(). Also an instance of a second script called "playback" will be included. This script manages the state of the player. Clicks on the player buttons call functions in the playback script.

Now when you press play for the very first time, the jPlayer object will be initialized, before finally the function playCurrent() is called to play the current MP3 file in the queue.

The initialization of the jPlayer object:

```
___jQuery("#"+player_ID).jPlayer({
        swfPath: scriptPath + "jquery.jplayer.swf",
        ready: function() {
            if (!stoppedByError) {
                // move the cursor to part 0 and play it
                if (!singleStringMode) {
                    moveCursor(0);
                }   
                console.log("FIRST START");
                // update the player status
                setPlayerStatus(1);
                // play the current text part
                playCurrent();
            }
        },
        ended: function(event) {
            if (!stoppedByError) {
                self.goToNext();
            }
        },
        errorAlerts: false,
        supplied: "mp3",
        error: function(event) {
            if (!stoppedByError) {
                handlePlayerError();
            }
        }
});
```

The code to start the playback (in the function playCurrent()):

```
___jQuery("#"+player_ID).jPlayer('setMedia', {
    mp3: textParts[currentPart].mp3
    //ogg: "sample.ogg"
}).jPlayer("play");
```

Of course the assigned URL of the MP3 (textParts[currentPart].mp3) is checked before this code to make sure the MP3 has successfully been transmitted from the server.

All of this works fine on desktop PCs in Chrome, Firefox and newer versions of IE. However, on some mobile devices (iOS, Android) there is a strange bug: When you press the play button for the first time, it changes to a pause button, but the playback does not start. Only when you press the button two more times (once to pause the playback and one more time to start it again), everything works as in desktop browsers.

I am aware that jPlayer's autoplay generally does not work on mobile devices, so this option is just turned off on mobile. But I can not find any good explanation why the playback fails at the first attempt. I used jConsole for mobile debugging and there wasn't any error.
One thing that I tried was to assign some silent dummy MP3 file to the jPlayer instance in the ready function to really make sure that some audio is available when the player is started for the first time, but it didn't help either.

This doesn't seem to be a general problem of jPlayer as I tested the demo sites for MP3 playback on the same devices and it works just fine. What is also very odd that the problem does not apply to Windows Mobile, just iOS and Android.

Any suggestions what could go wrong in the process of initializing jPlayer and starting it for the first time?